Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307) CRA
My React app was made using create react app typescript template.
This is the folder structure:

I get an error saying module cannot be found when I try import it in a .tsx file like below. Even IntelliSense shows all the folder options until the very end where it doesn't provide any options for images.
import Hello from "../Assets/Images/Hello.png";

What should I do? I want to be able to import static resources, so they are included automatically by webpack when I build the app.
I added a index.d.ts in src with the following code but it didnt work
declare module "*.jpg";
declare module "*.png";


Does this answer your question? Importing images in TypeScript React - "Cannot find module"
